# Relay.js - Not receiving props, only __dataId__

Tags: javascript, reactjs, relay, graphql-js

So I'm trying to figure out Relay.js. I conjured simple app that basically imitates example on Relay's website. However although I've managed to get rid of errors in both consoles (node and chrome), my component doesn't receive fragments I specified in Raley.Container. I have no idea, where the problem could be, as my app looks pretty much like Relay's example.

Note that map method on `this.props.companies` isn't available as it is an object, with 1 property, that is __dataId__.

First Component

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.companies.map((comapny => <Company company={company} />))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Relay.createContainer(App, {
  fragments: {
    companies: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Companies {
        companies { ${Company.getFragment('company')} }
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

Second component

```
class Company extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.comapany.name}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Relay.createContainer(Company, {
  fragments: {
    company: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Company {
        __id,
        name
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

And my Route

```
class AppHomeRoute extends Relay.Route {
  static routeName = 'Comapnies';
  static queries = {
    companies: (Component) => Relay.QL`
      query {
        companies { ${Component.getFragment('companies')} }
      }
    `,
  };
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. I have a list of events that I fetch with artists playing at that event, I tap on an artist, it shows the artist info and the events that that artist will be playing in, but the first event I tap on won't show up as the artist's event since it only returns `__dataID__`.

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: @ChrisHarrison I managed to get one occurrence of this solved, but I can't fix another one that popped up.. have you?